# Error in parsing a simple grammar with pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to parse a simple regex grammar with concatenation, disjunction, and kleene star. My grammar and tests look like this:

```
from pyparsing import Word, nums, Forward, Suppress, OneOrMore

#A grammar for a simple class of regular expressions
number = Word(nums)('number')
lparen = Suppress('(')
rparen = Suppress(')')

expression = Forward()('expression')

concatenation = expression + expression
concatenation.setResultsName('concatenation')

disjunction = lparen + OneOrMore(expression + Suppress('|')) + expression + rparen
disjunction.setResultsName('disjunction')

kleene = lparen + expression + rparen + Suppress('*')
kleene.setResultsName('kleene')

expression << number | concatenation | disjunction | kleene

#Test a simple input
tests = """
7
23
(7)*
(45)*
(1|2|3)
((2)*|3)
((0|1))*
""".splitlines()

for t in tests:
    print t
    print expression.parseString(t)
    print
```

However, the program fails on the very first test:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 34, in <module>
    print expression.parseString(t)
  File "/home/elliot/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1216, in parseString
    raise exc
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected W:(0123...) (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

What's the problem here? Also, any other feedback on my grammar (i.e. how I could have done things better/simpler) would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first test is not `"7"`. The first test is `""`, because your `tests` string starts with an empty line. `""` does not match a valid expression in your grammar.

Comment: Ok, I fixed that, but now it fails on `(7)*`, with 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser.py", line 34, in <module>
    print expression.parseString(t)
  File "/home/elliot/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1216, in parseString
    raise exc
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected W:(0123...) (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)`. Any ideas?

Comment: It should match expression -> kleene -> number

Comment: @RenéG: Part of the problem is that you need parentheses in `expression << number | concatenation | disjunction | kleene`, since `<<` has higher precedence than `|`. Part of the problem is that your parser will recurse infinitely trying to parse a `concatenation`.

Comment: Why will it recurse infinitely? I just added the parentheses and it started recursing infinitely on `(7)*`, which is a `kleene`. What's the problem?

Comment: @RenéG: How do you parse a `concatenation`? Well, first you try to parse an `expression`. How do you parse an `expression`? Well, you try to parse a `number`, and when that doesn't work, you try to parse a `concatenation`. How do you parse a `concatenation`?

Comment: The concatenation would have numbers at some level though. Like `(7)*(7|8)`, that would be a concatenation of two expressions, a kleene and a disjunction, which have numbers at their base. So it should work. But when I try to parse `(7)*`, I get an infinite recursion.

Comment: Oh wait never mind I figured it out! I just had to move concatenation to the end of the list!

Comment: @RenéG: The parser doesn't know it's a `kleene`. It won't consider that possibility until it finishes figuring out whether the expression can be parsed as a `number`, `concatenation`, or `disjunction`, and it'll never finish considering the `concatenation` case.

Comment: Yup, moving concatenation to the end fixed it. Thanks!